Gradle does not see log field through @Log4j2 annotation inside lombok in InteliJ
I have a class
@Log4j2
public class TestClass {
    public void doSmth() {
        log.info("doSmth");
    }
}

When I try to compile my code using gradle (tap on "assemble" button assemble it fails with the error:

error: cannot find symbol
log.info("������ ������:"); symbol:   variable log.

By the way, if I try to use it in another project, it compiles fine. I'm stuck for a day.
I have such dependencies in gradle.build:
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

Please, if anybody has such an issue, share with me how to resolve this.
UPDATE: It seems to be trouble in lombok. Because it does not see lombok methods:
DataClass.java
@Data
public class DataClass {
    private String data = "abc";
}

TestClass.java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DataClass().setData("123");
}

After assemble:

error: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method setData(String)

I have read many posts and tried doing this:

Reinstall Lombok plugin
Change dependencies on:

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'


Enable Preferences > Compiler > Annotation Processors like in this post: Building with Lombok's @Slf4j and Intellij: Cannot find symbol log
Nothing help. The most interesting, as I said, another project compiles fine with

compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'


Maybe problem in other dependencies?
